# WIndows authentication in Blazor Server Side Application

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server Side application which uses windows authentication. This works fine and I can see the correct user logged in.

But when I try to access another api which is internal to our network, it authenticates on the api as the AppPool user instead.

How would I be able to access the api resource as the logged in windows user and not as the App Pool user?

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem. server Blazor Web API with Windows authentication. Could you solve this problem, please?

Comment: Maybe Integrated Windows Authentication can be the solution.

Comment: I landed up using a jwt which can retain the user context using the token.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Blazor Server App) and all it took was to change a little the ConfigureServices in Startup.cs:

From:

```
services.AddAuthentication();
```

To:

```
services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```